# Когда можно опускать шаблонные аргументы у класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Какое правило языка позволяет опускать шаблонные аргументы у классов? Когда это можно делать и что подставляется на место аргумента? Например, почему можно написать `std::less<>` здесь?

```
std::map<A, B, std::less<>>
```

Почему нельзя просто `std::less`?

Comment: К такому вопросу очень актуально было бы указать версию стандарта.

Comment: @user207200 последняя, если не указано иного

Comment: Аргумент шаблона у `std::less` можно опустить по той причине, что есть аргумент-тип по-умолчанию `void`. Просто написать `std::less` нельзя, т.к. такого типа нет.

Comment: можно опустить, если аргумент шаблона можно иначе вывести:  Например:   std::vector<int> v;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значения параметров шаблона, можно опускать, если для этих параметров определены значения по умолчанию. (Также как и для аргументов функций.)  Для [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) - значение по умолчанию - `void` начиная с с++14  .  Т.е. `std::less<>` - конкретный тип данных эквивалентный `std::less<void>` но не эквивалентный `std::less`, который является шаблоном класса, а не классом. (`std::map` в качестве третьего аргумента требует именно конкретный тип данных, а не шаблон.)

Замечу, что специализация шаблона [`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void), также была введена в C++14, и она отличается от специализаций этого шаблона другими типами. В нем определена функция сравнения гетерогенный типов данных, (например, сравнение std::string со std::string_view), и не требует приведения к общему типу данных в промежуточных вычислениях, если в ищите в map по ключу, тип актуального значения которого отличается от типа, указанного в map.

Comment: Не понял. Где и какая функция определена?

Comment: функция `opernator()`, очевидно. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void