# Когда можно опускать пустые угловые скобки?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1406853) можно использовать `std::less` с пустыми скобками `std::less<>`, но нельзя без них `std::less`. В то время как [этот код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406853/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0#comment2501039_1406853) принимает оба варианта:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less()); 

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<>());
```

Почему так? Когда можно опустить `<>`, а когда нельзя?

Comment: а вы сами как думаете? Если итераторы указывают на элементы, типы которых известны компилятору, и на эти элементы применяется  объект шаблонного класса, то компилятор спокойно выводит тип инстанцирования из типа элемента.  Этот процесс выведения типа называем deduction guides . Если можно вывести тип из инициализатора, аргумента  или другими путями, то он выводится, если нет, то придется  явно указать аргумент шаблона. Так сделано в первом случаи, потому что std::less<> это тип, передаваемый в аргумент шаблона, и не откуда вывести по какому типу генерировать.

Comment: В целом: если возможно сделать что то полезное , где не нужна дополнительная информация, то современные компиляторы это делают.

Answer (score 3):

`std::less` - шаблон класса. Возможность не писать после него шаблонные аргументы называется [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (class template argument deduction - вывод аргументов для шаблонов классов).

В общем случае это позволяет не только убирать `<>`, но и угадывать шаблонные аргументы из аргументов конструктора.

Ищем "class template argument deduction" в предметном указателе стандарта, находим:

[`[dcl.type.class.deduct]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#1)

> If a placeholder for a deduced class type appears as a *decl-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of an initializing declaration ([dcl.init]) of a variable, the declared type of the variable shall be cv T, where T is the placeholder.

Т. е. первый случай - это разрешено в "инициализирующих объявлениях" переменных, если в типе кроме имени класса нет ничего кроме `const` и `volatile` (никаких `*`, `[]`, и т. п.).

Что еще за "инициализирующее объявление"? [`[dcl.init.general]/21`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-21) объясняет, что это то же самое, что определение переменной, за исключением вот этой ситуации:

```
struct A {static const int x = 1;};
const int A::x;
```

В которой инициализирующее объявление - первое (потому что там инициализатор), а определение - второе.

Но это не единственный случай, где это разрешено. Читаем дальше:

[`[dcl.type.class.deduct]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#2)

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also be used in the type-specifier-seq in the new-type-id or type-id of a new-expression ([expr.new]), as the simple-type-specifier in an explicit type conversion (functional notation), or as the type-specifier in the parameter-declaration of a template-parameter ([temp.param]).
> A placeholder for a deduced class type shall not appear in any other context.

Т. е. еще это разрешено в:

- Вызовах `new`.
- C-style кастах в фунциональной записи, т.е. `класс(...)` можно, а `(класс)...` нельзя.
- В типах NTTP (non-type template parameters - шаблонных параметров, не являющихся типами). На этом основана [возможность передавать строки в шаблонные параметры](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024633/2752075).